# problem with DataBinder

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the DataBinder.Eval in different place in my asp page but in one place it makes an error

> 'System.Web.UI.DataBinder' does not contain a definition for 'eval'

It work in this line

```
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Correz.">
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
         <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="Linkbutton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="IsVisible"
         Text="<img src=images/IsVisible.gif border=0 alt='Fax correzione'>" Visible='<%#IsVisible(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.FlgSta"),DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.FlgCon"))%>'>
                                        </asp:LinkButton>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateColumn>
```

But I got the error in this link in enabled!!

```
                                                                                <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Modif">
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Modifica" Enabled='<%#IsEnabled(DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.FlgNote"),DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.FlgCon"))%>'                                   
                                                 Text='<%#CheckLocked(DataBinder.eval(Container,"DataItem.Ididis"),DataBinder.eval(Container,"DataItem.Prodis")) %>' 
                                                 Visible='<%#Visibile(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.FlgNote"),DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.FlgCon"))%>'>
                                        </asp:LinkButton>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateColumn>
```

I can’t found why !!

Comment: Can you share more code from your aspx page? Share the full code for the control(s) that you are trying to bind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the below line, Eval is typed in Lower Case. it should be `Eval`, not `eval`. Remember C# is case Sensitive :)

```
Text='<%#CheckLocked(DataBinder.eval(Container,"DataItem.Ididis"),DataBinder.eval(Container,"DataItem.Prodis")) %>'
```

Comment: but the error in the Enabled the line before : even I correct it but the same problem I get

Comment: did you correct 2 instances of the typo? the error clearly says no definition for 'eval'!? is it the same error again?